# Is there a way to detect why an Ajax call does not make it to a controller in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to make an AJAX call when I click on a button. My program should send a request to the server to fetch some data and display it on the page. To keep things simple I first need to understand how I could make the AJAX call to work. I tried the following:

My controller in ASP.Net MVC5 C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public string MyMethod(int somePara)
{
    return "it worked";
}
```

My AJAX call:

```js
$("button#test").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: loc + "/MyMethod",
    data: somePara = "",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" id="test">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    Test
</button>
```

(Where `loc` field within the AJAX call would define my controller.)

When I run this code locally, my AJAX call will return the error part.

What should I change? Is there a way I could detect why this is happening?

Comment: yes check your console

Comment: It will say `POST https://localhost:[portnumber]/MyController/MyMethod 500` @JuniusL.

Comment: that's internal server error, which means something happened on your backend

Comment: please log your URL first and check is it proper

Comment: 'data: somePara = "",' doesn't look correct to me, shouldn't you stringify that? Or at least put it in json context

Comment: Apparently the problem was the method name. I was using the same method name but using a different signature, somehow the program did not enjoy that and returned the internal server error. I fixed it by renaming the method to a unique name. @JuniusL. Next problem I have is actually displaying the value from the controller on the page which I believe has something to do with the `data` part of my AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues of your request

- Not correct data format `somePara = "111"` => `JSON.stringify({ somePara: "111" }),`
- Did not defined dataType

  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
- Action did not return JSON format.

Controller action

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult MyMethod(int somePara)
    {
        return Json("it worked", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

AJAX

```
 $("button#test").on("click", function () {


       $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:  "/Home/MyMethod", // i try home controller
                    data: JSON.stringify({ somePara: "111" }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error")
                    }
                });
            });
```

Update: the action should change to `MyMethod(int? somePara)` to prevent `somePara : ""` cant cast to int.

Comment: There's no need to use `JSON.stringify` with `data:` just use and object with `:` not `=`: `data: { somePara : "" },`

Comment: yes, in this case we can use data: { somePara : "" }

Comment: When I use the exact same code above, it will keep returning internal server error, but when I remove the parameter, it works fine. How could I send a parameter without getting this error?

Comment: to prevent error, you should use int? MyMethod(int? somePara) to prevent

Comment: I have no clue what was causing the problem, but copying the whole thing over again, pasting it within my solution and comparing the codes I did not find anything and magically it's working now. So nevermind my last comment.